# C++ struct pointer and memory leak

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks

I am doing a c++ book question and got stucked on this specific parts where it says

"write program that asks how many score there are and how many student there are. it should then dynamically allocate an array of structures, each structure's Test member should point to a dynamically allocated array that will hold the test scores,after array has been dynamically allocated the program should ask for the id number and test score for each student".

right now I have a problem in the for loop where there is a memory leak and program crashes after input values, any suggestions ?

#### here is the code:

```
struct Course
{
      string Name;
      int IdNumber;
      int *Tests;
      int Average;
      int courseGrade;
};

void Result(int,int );

int main()
{
    cout<<"please enter number of test score ";
     int testScore;
     cin>>testScore;
     int numberofStudents;
     cout<<"please enter number of student there is ";
     cin>>numberofStudents;
     Result(numberofStudents,testScore);
}

void Result(int numberofStudents,int testScore)
{
      const int Size=numberofStudents;
      const int Size1=testScore;
      Course *object=nullptr;
      object=new Course[numberofStudents];
      object->Tests = new int[testScore];
      for(int i=0;i<testScore;i++)
      {
           cin>>object[i].Tests[i];
      }
}
```

#### here is the input on the console

```
please enter number of the test scores :3
please enter number of students there is :3
34
90
```

the program crashes after I input 90

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: You call `new`. You never call `delete`.

Comment: You only allocate `Tests` for the very first element of the `object` array with this line: `      object->Tests = new int[testScore];`.

Comment: Please show some sample input so that we can better assist you.

Comment: The memory leaks aside (there are several), you need an outer loop for your students, then an inner loop for each student's test scores. You're using the same index `i` for both students and scores with a single loop, and in so doing, performing a somewhat "diagonal" population (first student <== first score, second student <== second score, etc). If the number of scores is greater than the number of students, this will invoke undefined behavior. It is clearly a bug.

Comment: @merlin2011 I doubt it is necessary. There are quite a few easy to spot bugs (too many to make this question worth answering.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I suspect is happening:

In this `for` loop:

```
  for(int i=0;i<testScore;i++)
  {
       cin>>object[i].Tests[i];
  }
```

You access `object` using `testScore` as an index. If `testScore` is larger than the length of `object` you will run into issues.

The memory leak problem comes from the fact that you are allocating space for `object` and every `Tests` member of a `Course` but you never free that memory.

Comment: Thank you! I am not clear about this where and how can i free memory

Comment: At the end of `Results()` you will need to loop through every element in `object` and call something like `delete object[i].Tests`. Then after that loop is complete, you'll have to call `delete[] object`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a memory leak because you are allocating things withj `new` and never freeing them with `delete`.

As for the crash, it's being caused by this line:

```
  object->Tests = new int[testScore];
```

Remember that `object` isn't a Course object, it's an *array* of Course objects, every one of which needs it's own `Tests` array.  The line is effectively just `object[0].Tests = ...`

So You need a loop on `numberofStudents`to allocate the test in each Course, and the another loop on `numberofStudents` around the loop on `testScore` (which you already have) to gather all the grades.   (Advanced study: you can combine those two loops)

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your code, and it doesn't crash anymore. Why you need to use pointer of Test. I think it is good to use static memory instead of dynamic memory. Please check this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

struct Course
{
      string Name;
      int IdNumber;
      int Tests[100];
      int Average;
      int courseGrade;
};

void Result(int,int );

int main()
{
    cout<<"please enter number of test score ";
     int testScore;
     cin>>testScore;
     int numberofStudents;
     cout<<"please enter number of student there is ";
     cin>>numberofStudents;
     Result(numberofStudents,testScore);
}

void Result(int numberofStudents,int testScore)
{
      const int Size=numberofStudents;
      const int Size1=testScore;
      Course *object=nullptr;
      object=new Course[numberofStudents];
      //object->Tests = new int[testScore];
      for(int i=0;i<testScore;i++)
      {
           cin>>object[i].Tests[i];
      }
}
```

Comment: Why you have unaccepted this answer from an accepted answer? What was the issue? Can you please elaborate?